# С# mvc 5 с базой данных

Tags: c#, sql, mvc

Я создал две модели. Один для игроков, а второе для клубов. Создал базу и заполнил. При запуске, данных об игроках нету.

Код:

```
public class Player

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public int? TeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
} 
public class Team

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Coach { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public Team()
    {
        Players=new List<Player>();
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{


    SoccerContext db = new SoccerContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var players = db.Players.Include(p=>p.Team);
        return View(players.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: С этого сайта я делаю https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.7.php

Comment: Смотрите строку подключения вашу, к какой БД вы подключаетесь и в какой бд вы держите данные. Скорее всего это разные бд.

Comment: Обратите  внимание на первые комментарии под статьей на metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.7.php . Там поясняется как сделать строку подключения. .

Comment: у меня там все нормально. Браузер открывает, там написано каталог игроков, а данные об игроков нету

Comment: как вы написали имя бд неправильно написано